# How to do sthg when cancellation request returns true?

Tags: c#

Below code starts counting and after 3 seconds, it will print the value of "i" variable. 
The program prints the variable but it does not print in the style that I wanted. It does not print the  Console.Writeline statement under if (token.IsCancellationRequested) part. I think the program directly exits when Cancellation request is true. Is it possible that I print out that console.writeline statement when cancellation request is true?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication17
{
class Program
{
    private static void Stop(CancellationTokenSource src)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        src.Cancel();
    }

    static void Count(CancellationToken token)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            Thread.Sleep(80);

            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Current number is :" + i.ToString());
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Clear();
            }

        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CancellationTokenSource src1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken tkn1 = new CancellationToken();

        var task1 = Task.Run(() => Count(tkn1), tkn1);
        var task2 = Task.Run(() => Stop(src1));
        task2.Wait();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your token is disconnected from `CancellationTokenSource`:

```
CancellationTokenSource src1 = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken tkn1 = new CancellationToken();
```

As you see - you just create new token without any relation to source. So when you request cancellation on token source - it cannot affect that token in any way. Instead of creating new token - use token from source:

```
CancellationToken tkn1 = src1.Token;
```

Note that there is also a race condition here:

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => Count(tkn1), tkn1);
var task2 = Task.Run(() => Stop(src1));
task2.Wait();
```

You are waiting for `task2` to complete, after that process immediately exits. `task2` is task that request token cancellation. After token is cancelled it might take up to 80ms (as per your code) for your loop to notice that and write a message. Before this happens - process might already have exited and you will see no message. To avoid that - wait for `task1` (actual loop) to complete instead:

```
 var task1 = Task.Run(() => Count(tkn1), tkn1);
 var task2 = Task.Run(() => Stop(src1));
 task1.Wait();
```

Comment: It is weird. When I add Console.Readline() instead of Task2.Wait(), I can get output as I wanted too. Maybe I should not wait for Task2? What do you think?

Comment: If I do not wait Task2 it does notprint anything.

Comment: @Lyrk I've updated answer with information about that.